# How to add line breaks in calculated columns without going into data view?

Tags: calculated-column, multiline-text-field

Just wondering how to create a list with line breaks in a calculated column without using data view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[social.technet.microsoft.com](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/9cfb6cdc-8a72-4e32-a34a-428edff48588) suggests that this can be achieved with " Shift + Enter "

Worth a try?

Steve

Comment: This works for sure inside =CONCATENATE()

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it depends on what you want the business rules to be around where the line breaks should appear and in how many places (all pages, just a single view, just on the forms, etc.).  You could probably do this with script added to the page(s).

Answer (score 1):

I've had a play around and I'm afraid I can't see a way to do this. The only two options I can think of are:

```
=CONCATENATE("A","
","B")
```

Which outputs `A B` because actual new lines are ignored by the HTML rendering.

or

```
=CONCATENATE("A","<br/>","B")
```

Which outputs `A<br/>B` because HTML output is escaped by SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `<br/>` in your column to indicate a line break. Then, add a script to your page to insert that text as html so that `<br/>` becomes an html line break.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function insertLineBreaks() {
    $("table.ms-listviewtable").find("td.ms-vb2").filter(":contains(<br/>)").each(
      function(){
        $(this).html('<div>'+$(this).text()+'</div>');
      });   
  }
  _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("insertLineBreaks");
</script>
```

Comment: This looks like a solution! Can the script be inside a content editor web part or does it have to be located in the main page html?

Comment: You should be able to put it in a Content Editor web part.

Comment: @Laurie - code works great until you set up the view to group your line items. Then it breaks and shows "<br/>" again. How do you get around the grouping so the code can access the list items again?

Comment: Is this solution taken from https://sites.google.com/site/sharepointhill/tutorials/mssp/line-break-calc-field ?

Answer (score 1):

Use Char(10) as a line break character.

Answer (score 0):

Include `<br/>` and return the calculated column as a number instead of a single line of text. For some reason, this returns html.